# Jquery children.length function not working in javascript array function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using children.length to determine if a div contains another div.

children.length returns an incorrect value when used in javascript array functions.

In the example below I would expect both values to be "1".

But, the javascript map function returns "0"

Why is this not working?

```js
let outerdiv = $(".outerdiv");

$("#first").text(outerdiv.first().children("div").length);

$("#second").text(outerdiv.map( o => $(o).children("div").length)[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outerdiv">
  <div class="innerdiv">
  </div>
</div>


outerdiv.first().children("div").length = <span id="first"></span>
<p>
outerdiv.map( o => $(o).children("div").length = <span id="second"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument passed to the `map` callback is the index, not the element, which is the second argument.

```js
let outerdiv = $(".outerdiv");
$("#first").text(outerdiv.first().children("div").length);
$("#second").text(outerdiv.map((i, el) => $(el).children("div").length)[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outerdiv">
  <div class="innerdiv">
  </div>
</div>
<span id="first"></span>
<br/>
<span id="second"></span>
```